# google maps marker custom image with dynamic letter on it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have an existing functionality for displaying a custom image .Here is the sample code for it .

```
var markerImageUrl = gmap_set_icons(email, 30);
var icon = {
    url: markerImageUrl, // url
    size: new google.maps.Size(40, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(30, 30),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)

};

marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng[i],
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```

gmap_set_icons is the function returns the url for the given email,however there could be no image with the email associated, in such case I would like to return a image created dynamically by using the first letter in the email and use it as a marker .Please let me know the best possible ways in doing it .

```
function gmap_set_icons(email,width){
var img = DEFAULT_GRAVATAR_url;
var default_image="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/83e524be3136955aeeb4272bd5a3adff.jpg?s=10&d=https://dpm72z3r2fvl4.cloudfront.net/css/images/user-default.png";

    if (email != undefined || email != "")
        return default_image;
    return 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/' + Agile_MD5("email") + '.jpg?s=' + width + "&d=" + escape(img);

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what does the variable `email` look like?  Is it a string, an object, ...?  What does the `gmap_set_icons` function look like?

Comment: hi duncan ,email is a string ,example : bounty@agilecc.com,In this case i need to show an image icon with 'B' on it .gmap_set_icons is just a function which returns url if there is an image with respect to email .I just updated my question with function ,please have a look.

Comment: isn't this the wrong way round? `if (email != undefined || email != "") return default_image;`  Surely you'd only want to use the default_image if email address *was* undefined or an empty string?  i.e. shouldn't it be `if (email == undefined || email == "") return default_image;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this site](http://googlemapsmarkers.com/) to get markers with letters on them, e.g.
http://googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/A/ff0000/ 
gives a red marker with a letter A.

Alternatively you can get them directly from Google:
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png
gives

[image]

In your function, you want to get the first letter of the email address, and convert it to its upper-case equivalent.

```
firstLetter = email.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
```

Then your image url would be like

```
'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker' + firstLetter + '.png';
```

The one thing I'm not sure of is how to tell if there's a Gravatar image for your email addresses.